# Manipulate and load image dynamically before opening modal to prevent flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm creating a page where users can upload images for a gallery. Upon selection of an image, I want to show a modal popup and allow the user to make a selection for the thumbnail. I'm using [jWindowCrop](https://github.com/tybro0103/jWindowCrop) for the same. The thumbnail should correspond to the aspect ratio of the image, therefore the thumbnail dimensions are being calculated dynamically.

I've managed to get all of this done, as seen in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9agfxpmc/).

```js
    $("input").change(function(e) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e1) {
        var img = new Image;
        img.onload = function() {
          $('#target').attr('src', e1.target.result);
          $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
            var $actualImageHeight = img.height;
            var $actualImageWidth = img.width;
            var aspectRatio = $actualImageWidth / $actualImageHeight;
            var thumbnailWidth = 300;
            var thumbnailHeight = thumbnailWidth / aspectRatio;
            var jwc = $('#target').getjWindowCrop();
            if (jwc != null) {
              jwc.destroy();
            }
            $('#target').jWindowCrop({
              targetWidth: thumbnailWidth,
              targetHeight: thumbnailHeight,
              loadingText: 'hello world',
              onChange: function(result) {
                $('#crop_x').text(result.cropX);
                $('#crop_y').text(result.cropY);
                $('#crop_w').text(result.cropW);
                $('#crop_h').text(result.cropH);
              }
            });
          }).modal('show');
        };
        img.src = reader.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.originalEvent.target.files[0]);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="fileContainer" class="col-md-8">
          <input type="file" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal-label" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <img id="target" alt="Source" />
    
            <div id="results">
              <b>X</b>: <span id="crop_x"></span>
              <br />
              <b>Y</b>: <span id="crop_y"></span>
              <br />
              <b>W</b>: <span id="crop_w"></span>
              <br />
              <b>H</b>: <span id="crop_h"></span>
              <br />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The problem I'm facing is that the actual image first loads, and then jWindowCrop() is invoked on that image which resizes it to the thumbnail size, but there's a flicker every time. I tried doing this on image `load()` event, but for some reason, the image dimensions were zero. I also tried doing it in the modal `show()` event, and I get the correct image dimensions as well, but jWindowCrop is unable to load the image. I do not get any errors in the console log as well. I'm confused why this happens.

The only way I was able to get it to work correctly was in the modal `shown()` event, but that leads to a flicker. I need the user to just see the jWindowCrop thumbnail selection frame without any flicker. How can I get this done?

Another problem I'm facing is that once a user selects an image, then closes the modal and selects another image, the thumbnail frame retains the previous image's dimensions before resizing to the current image thumbnail dimension. But I guess if my first problem is solved, this will too.